# SSIS package connecting to SALESFORCE with OR (parameter = 'Y')

Tags: soql

I have an SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) 2008 package where Salesforce.com is the data source, and the below SOQL works fine to connect, taking the variable dt_last_success value that is the last time the package ran.

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM Health_Plan__History
WHERE  CreatedDate > <@User::dt_last_success>
```

I'd like to add an OR clause such that if the char(1) variable @User::load_all_data = 'Y', it ignors the @dt_last_success and loads all data.  When I try the below, I get an error in the below image.

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM Health_Plan__History
WHERE  CreatedDate > <@User::dt_last_success> 
   OR <@User::load_all_data> 'Y'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [where syntax](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm) in SOQL is limited to only use [field expressions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm#fieldexpression) which are of this form:

> fieldName comparisonOperator value

So your "value comparisonOperator value" isn't allowed - by the time the query reaches Salesforce that is what the query has been turned into - and neither is "fieldName comparisonOperator fieldName".

You will have to look for a solution at the SSIS side e.g. leave out the where clause altogether if your flag is 'Y'.